# Load image from folder in reactjs datafile and pass to jsx file

Tags: reactjs

I have a file I consider my data file, where I use it to populate a reactjs slider.
So instead of having 5 of the same components copy and pasted.

The problem is, I'm also passing an image and I cannot get it to show when my image is local.

```
  <Slider {...settings}>
    {school.schoolData.map((schoolData, index) => (
      <a href={schoolData.Register} target="_blank">
        {" "}
        <div
          className="contentContainer"
          style={{ textAlign: "center" }}
        >
          <img
            src={schoolData.Logo} 
            style={{ width: "150px", textAlign: "center" }}
          />
        </div>
      </a>
    ))}
  </Slider>
```

And this is my file I use for my data.

```
import testimage from "../../../../public/exchanges/testimage.png";

 


export default {
  schoolData: [
    {
      id: 1,
      Register: serviceIcon1,
      title: "Price",
      body: "The highly the not having with lively Our up with.",
      Link:"www.google.com",
     // Logo: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ee/Chain_link_icon.png",
     Logo:testimage 
    },
```

I have used the public folder, the asset folder, tried importing the image but nothing works.
However, if I just pass a weblink it works.
Appreciated if I could be assisted in using my local images.

Regards

More Info
`icon: serviceIcon1,` is an icon and to get it to work I must say `src={schoolData.Logo.src}`  but if I use `.src` with the image it gives an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it,
I had to say `Logo:testimage.src`

Answer (score 0):

The bug is where your defined the image address. Please remove curley braces from testImage. It should be

> Logo: testImage

Because when you put braces, It becomes an object now, but **< img />** tag expects string as source.
So basicaly your data will look like this.

```
import testimage from "../../../../public/exchanges/testimage.png";

export default {
 schoolData: [
   {
    id: 1,
    Register: serviceIcon1,
    title: "Price",
    body: "The highly the not having with lively Our up with.",
    Link:"www.google.com",
    Logo: testimage
   },
```

You can check my CodeSandbox example as well [HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-frog-5u3z0?file=/src/App.js)

***BONUS TIP:*** when you use the public folder you don't need to put lots of

> "../../../../public/exchange/etc"

. You can access the public folder from anywhere directly like this

> "/public/exchange/etc"

Comment: Actually that did not work.
I'm getting a `[object Object]` cannot be found and when I inspect the page `[object Object]` is the src

Comment: I just tried the sandbox and it works, probably react cant import the picture?

Answer (score 0):

Do not put the images into the public folder. Instead, use the src folder for all assets and scripts.